# Search a variable after its value in debug mode, is it possible?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, debugging

I am dealing with legacy code and in UI I can find some ID's of my objects which are used at run time. 
 Those id's could help me to find more quickly the portion of code with which I am dealing for that requirement, but I do not know if it is possible to do in debug mode from Visual Studio 2010 (C++ and C#) a search after a value of an object, which was already calculated at run time.

If you have an idea if this can be done or another way to do it (search an object's value in debug mode) or some work around give me a hand, this could save many many, hours of work for each bug with which I will deal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what your asking but Scott Guru's tips and tricks might help you out.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/08/18/debugging-tips-with-visual-studio-2010.aspx

Comment: Thank you very much for posting, to be more explicit i will give an example, for instance at runtime in a text filed will occurs 33 value after some calculations or events, i want to search in debug mode to see in code which variable has that value (it does not matter if more variables have that value, because in my case i am dealing with objects id's which i can get from UI at runtime).

Comment: Take a look at the section on custom actions on break points, it sounds like a custom macro might be able to do what your looking for.